# how to combine data from multiple tables into one master table using sql

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables (JM, JCD, and JEO). JM is the parent with PK JobNo. JCD and JEO are both children to JM with FK's JobNo.

Below is the desired output table from the 3 tables I am writing the query for (sorry about the terrible formatting - it won't let me post images yet :( )

**JM**

```
JobNo
------    
13088
13100
```

**JCD**

```
JobNo   CostType Amount
----------------------------    
13088   10  100
13088   10  105
13088   23  120
13088   24  130
13088   25  140
13088   26  50
13088   90  50
13100   25  5
13100   90  10
```

**JEO**

```
JobNo   CostType    Estimate
-------------------------------------    
13088   10  50
13088   11  60
13088   24  10
13088   30  100
13100   25  310
```

**OUTPUT**

```
JobNo   CostType Amount Estimate
------------------------------------
13088   10      100 0                   
13088   10  105 0                   
13088   23  120 0                   
13088   24  130 0                   
13088   25  140 0                   
13088   26  50  0                   
13088   10  0   50                  
13088   11  0   60                  
13088   24  0   10                  
13088   30  0   100                 
13100   25  5   0                   
13100   25  0   310
```

Any ideas on what the code would be to achieve this?

(Note the resultant table does not include any rows where JCD.CostType is equal to 90).

I have tried something like this, but it doesn't work :(

```
SELECT JM.JobNo, JCD.CostType, JCD.Amount, JEO.Estimate
FROM JM
FULL OUTER JOIN JCD ON JM.JobNo = JCD.JobNo
FULL OUTER JOIN JEO ON JM.JobNo = JEO.JobNo
WHERE JCD.CostType != 90
GROUP BY JM.JobNo, JCD.CostType, JCD.Amount, JEO.Estimate
```

Comment: You could use UNION and select both separately.

Comment: could you show me how? I'm quite new to sql.

Comment: Probably not that important for this question, but you should state which DBMS (Postgres, Oracle, ...) you are using

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  JM.JobNo, JCD.CostType, JCD.Amount, 0 as Estimate
FROM 
  JM, JCD 
WHERE 
  JCD.CostType != 90 AND JM.JobNo = JDC.JobNo
GROUP BY 
  JM.JobNo, JCD.CostType, JCD.Amount 

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  JM.JobNo, JCD.CostType, 0 as Amount,  JEO.Estimate 
FROM 
  JM, JEO
WHERE 
  JM.JobNo = JEO.JobNo
GROUP BY 
  JM.JobNo, JCD.CostType, JCD.Estimate 
ORDER BY 
 JM.JobNo
```

Comment: @user2834719 good! I hope you will accept this answer when you have enough points.